# Source does not contain any versions of 'rails-assets-lodash (~> 2.4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, bower

I'm trying to help debug a project. I'm getting a really weird error when I try to run the server. I tried to google the gem but no luck. Anyone have any ideas?  I tried `bundle install` and `bundle update`.

Here is the actual block of code I'm trying to run.

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  # Assets via Bower
  gem 'rails-assets-lodash', '~> 2.4'
  gem 'rails-assets-angular', '~> 1.2'
  gem 'rails-assets-angular-spree', '= 0.0.2'
end
```

> error: Source does not contain any versions of 'rails-assets-lodash (~> 2.4) ruby' Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

If I comment out the first gem I get similar error with the gem proceeding it. When I comment out the block it does work though, but I was instructed not to change the environment.

Comment: This may be an old name for the lodash-rails gem.  Try using `gem 'lodash-rails' in your Gemfile instead of `gem 'rails-assets-lodash`.

Comment: I saw that gem originally but I think they are trying to do something different with the block it is in.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bundler 1.8.0-1.8.2, you are probably hitting this bug: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3414

This should be fixed in Bundler 1.8.3 (released today).